# Jersey REST service changing bytes of multipart request

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I have a REST service using Jersey 2.25.1, running on Tomcat 7.  I am using Jersey's FormDataMultiPart class to accept file uploads.  I can receive the files totally fine, but the ones that are not text (or xml, etc) are having some of their bytes changed to the Unicode Replacement Character.  I have tried various files (docx, pdf, etc) and it happens to all of them.

For example, I can clearly see that a file with hex byte D2 is being replaced with EF BF BD (ascii ï¿½).  Other bytes are being replaced as well.  This obviously corrupts the files so they cannot be opened after coming through the service.

My Service:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response call(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart) {

    Response response;

    try {

        for (String attachName : formDataMultiPart.getFields().keySet()) {

            FormDataBodyPart bodyPart = formDataMultiPart.getField(attachName);
            byte[] content = bodyPart.getEntityAs(byte[].class);
            InputStream inputStream = bodyPart.getEntityAs(InputStream.class);
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\temp", attachName))) {
                    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            }

        }

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Files successfully uploaded.").build();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }

    return response;

}
```

My test code:

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();

FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();

formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("uploadTestFile1.docx",
            new File("MYFILE.docx"),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));

final WebTarget target = client.target("MYURL");
final Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(formDataMultiPart, formDataMultiPart.getMediaType()));

formDataMultiPart.close();
formDataMultiPart.close();
```

Could it be related to http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Multipart-Form-And-Encoding-td3931049.html

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm thinking Tomcat is replacing the bytes after Jersey sends its request but before FormDataMultiPart consumes the response.  When I remove -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 from the Tomcat parameters, different bytes get changes (to different other bytes).  I wouldn't expect character encoding should get involved at all since the Content-Type is "multipart/form-data".  The bytes should get sent as is.